# How to multiply matrix with 3 dimensions using GPU in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, gpu

The opencv documentation says GpuMat works only for two-dimensional matrix, however I abstracts an matrix of three dimensions on a two, and I use a loop to multiply these two matrices using `gpu::gemm`

```
for (int k = 0; k <C, k ++) {
    gpu::gemm (matrix_a.colRange (Range (k * M (k + 1) * M)),
    matrix_b.rowRange (Range (k * M (k + 1) * M)),
    N [k + 1], matrix_c, 1, matrix_c);
}
```

Where M is used to shift for the other matrix.
`matrix_a` `matrix_b` and `matrix_c` are `gpu::GpuMat`

As you can see, the loop is serial, what I would like to do is to parallelize the whole operation, has someone any suggestion?

Comment: "aguma suggestions"`?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @talonmies.

Comment: I might be wrong but as far as I can tell the results of these solutions are not dependent on each other. With that in mind why not just spawn 4 threads and have them each loop with +=4 and be offset from each other. Or are you looking for something more advanced like this? http://apps.cs.utexas.edu/tech_reports/reports/tr/TR-2087.pdf